# how to get specific key from a variable in node

Tags: javascript, node.js

Im working on a Auth flow. A private project for me and some friends

My code is getting raw from A website then its put it  into a vatiable.

An example of what is inside the variable

```
{
   "token": "mytoken",
   "id": "testid"
}
```

I would like to get the value of token and print it

Comment: My code is getting raw from A website then its put it into a vatiable. what's the type of data your getting ?

Comment: `yourVariableName.token`?

Comment: Is the data in a JSON string?  Or already parsed into a Javascript variable?  What does `console.log(typeof yourVariable)` show?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
let raw = {
   "token": "mytoken",
   "id": "testid"
}
```

Then `raw.token` or `raw["token"]` should do the trick.

Comment: The answer here depends upon whether the data is already parsed into a Javascript variable or is still raw JSON.  We don't know that yet.